# Navigation bar missing when Use Autolayout unchecked

Tags: ios, autolayout

I built an app using xcode 4.5, target ios6.0. Works great in simulator. I then try to run on my 5.1 (1st gen iPad). It crashes with NSLayoutConstraint error.

I then set my target for 5.1, and uncheck Use Autolayout. Now it runs, but the Navigation Bar is missing.

This is now true for both device & simulator if Use Autolayout unchecked, for either 5.1 or 6.0 target.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this. I accepted answers (including my own) for all of my questions that have acceptable (or any) answers.

Answer (score 1):

I just met exactly the same problem and solved it by myself. Hope this is useful for you.

1. Select MainStoryboard.storyboard in the project navigator to open the canvas.
2. Drag the Navigation Bar a little bit.

Rebuild and then the missing Navigation Bar will appear again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So when you switch to 'old style' layout, you need to insure that your view has properly set whether there is nav bar, a tab bar, etc.

In this mode you need to insure that also the struts and springs are proper.